# CodeIgniter routing in Google App Engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine

After some hard work getting CI to work initially in App Engine, I am struggling when it comes to routes.

My index controller works, as do any controllers that are in the root controller folder.

However, anything that is inside a folder e.g. controllers/admin/index.php doesn't work.

Running on a LAMP stack, this would work fine, without any extra routing.

Do I need to add a new route, and if so, what should it be?

Or do I need to add in a handler in the app.yaml file, again, if so, what should it be?

My app.yaml file at the moment looks like this:

```
application: <project-name>
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

And this works (well, I can access the main index controller and other top level controller scripts (controllers/index.php, controllers/page.php etc))

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work.." What errors are you getting? Can you share the error log?

Comment: Your app.yaml file looks fine. Did you add the corresponding  mapping in application/config/routes.php? See http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html for more details.

Comment: The server gives me a blank page, with a 500 server response (Checked in Dev tools). As for the routing, I haven't touched it from what it was for the LAMP setup (where I can access admin via http://localhost/admin). Should it be different /modified? If so, to what?

Comment: Just to add, for the routing, I never needed to add a route to access "controllers/admin/index.php".

Comment: Just checked my logs, and it seems like my extended core controllers are not being found. I have MY_Controller (which extends CI_Controller, and is loaded OK) but then my two other controllers (which extend MY_Controller) are not being found. I have the code in config.php to load them as well (this setup worked 100% on a typical Apache+PHP setup

Comment: Has this got anything to do with your CI not working recently?
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#Updated_PHP_SELF

Comment: @KhairulAnwarHassim I'll have to dig deeper. If it is, its a CI issue really. Any idea how I can go about testing and trying to fix this?

Comment: Are you using CI 3.0.1?

Comment: We are using v2 I'm afraid